# Flutter sharedpreferences get data after app restart

Tags: flutter

I have implemented the shared preferences which is used to store the current logged in user, i can get the username in each and every time after the user log in, however after the app is restart, the username is gone but the current user is still logged in. I attached the gif to have better explaination. Below is my code.

[image]

**main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var usernamee = prefs.getString('yourusername');
print(usernamee);
runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: usernamee == null
      ? LoginPage()
      : MainPage(
          username: username,
        )));
}

String username = '';
```

**loginpage.dart**

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
LoginPageState createState() => LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

TextEditingController user = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController pass = new TextEditingController(); 

String txtmsg = '';

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
}

Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
            content: new Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: new Text('No'),
              ),
              new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                child: new Text('Yes'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
    ) ??
    false;
}

Future<List> _login() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

final response =
    await http.post("http://192.168.1.2/login/login.php", body: {
  "username": user.text,
  "password": pass.text,
});

var datauser = json.decode(response.body);

if (datauser.length == 0) {
  setState(() {
    txtmsg = "Username or password is wrong, please try again.";
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: txtmsg);
  });
} else {
  if (datauser[0]['level'] == 'admin') {
    prefs.setString('yourusername', '$username');
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext ctx) => MainPage(
                  username: username,
                )));
  }

  setState(() {
    username = datauser[0]['username'];
  });
}
print(username);
return datauser;
}

final logo = Hero(
tag: 'hero',
child: CircleAvatar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  radius: 48.0,
  child: Image.asset('assets/images/ic_launcher.png'),
),
);

final forgotLabel = FlatButton(
child: Text(
  'Forgot password?',
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
),
onPressed: () {},
);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil.getInstance()..init(context);
ScreenUtil.instance =
    ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);

return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onWillPop,
    child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          logo,
          SizedBox(height: 48.0),
          Center(
            child: FormUI(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )));
}

Widget FormUI() {
return new Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    TextFormField(
      controller: user,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Username',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0),
        border:
            OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
      validator: validateusername,
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 18.0),
    TextFormField(
      controller: pass,
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Password',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0),
        border:
            OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
      validator: validatepassword,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(40),
    ),
    RaisedButton(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      ),
      onPressed: () => _login(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      child: Text('Log In', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    ),
    forgotLabel,
  ],
);
}

String validateusername(String value) {
if (value.length == 0) {
  return "Name is Required";
}

return null;
}

String validatepassword(String value) {
if (value.length == 0) {
  return "Password is Required";
}

return null;
}
}
```

**mainpage.dart**

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
MainPage({this.username});
final String username;

@override
MainPageState createState() => MainPageState();
}

class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
            content: new Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: new Text('No'),
              ),
              new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                child: new Text('Yes'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
    ) ??
    false;
}

void showWifiAlert() async {
var wifiEnabled = await getWifiStatus();
if (wifiEnabled) {
  //Do stuff
} else {
  AlertDialog(
    title: Center(
      child: Text('Alert'),
    ),
    content: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            'Please connect to the internet',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        child: Text(
          'Ok',
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}
}

Future<bool> getWifiStatus() async {
try {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    print('connected');
    return true;
  }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
  print('not connected');
  return false;
}
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
String username;
print(username);
showWifiAlert();

return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: _onWillPop,
  child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          widget.username,
        ),
      ),
      drawer: new DrawerOnly()),
);
}
}

class DrawerOnly extends StatefulWidget {
@override
DrawerOnlyState createState() => DrawerOnlyState();
}

class DrawerOnlyState extends State<DrawerOnly> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
return new Drawer(
    child: new ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      accountName: Text('$username'),
      accountEmail: null,
      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
        child: FlutterLogo(size: 42.0),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    new ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.library_music),
      title: Text('Fragment 1'),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(ctxt);
        Navigator.push(ctxt,
            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new FirstFragment()));
      },
    ),
    new ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.movie),
      title: Text('Fragment 2'),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(ctxt);
        Navigator.push(ctxt,
            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new SecondFragment()));
      },
    ),
    new ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
      title: Text('Logout'),
      onTap: () async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.remove('yourusername');
        Navigator.pushReplacement(ctxt,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => LoginPage()));
        /* Navigator.pop(ctxt);
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(ctxt, '/landingpage'); */
      },
    ),
  ],
));
}
}
```

How do i able to get the username even the app is restarted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figure out, i had to add this code in the `mainpage.dart`. Below is the snippet.

```
loadUsername() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
setState(() {
  username = prefs.getString('yourusername');
});
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
loadUsername();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the value on `initState` not in the main method.

Comment: I fetch the value on the main method because is the let the current user stay logged in, so to your answer, how to i fetch the value and on which `initState`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var username;
getUsername() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  username = prefs.getString('yourusername');
}

@override
  void initState() {
    getUsername()
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: May i ask why add print(username)? What i'm trying to do is get back the username after the app is restart. I can only get the username after each time user login but after the app restart the username is gone, so how do i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

i use it like that, on my splashscreen and it works perfectly

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    token();
  }

  token() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = prefs.getString('userToken');
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
      if (token == null || token == '') {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
      } else {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use **setUser()** [retrieve preferences values] just before **super.initState();**

```
  @override
    void initState() {
     setUser();
     super.initState();
    }

    setUser() async{
       preferences=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      setState(() {
        userId = preferences.getString(USERID) ?? "ak id";
        userName = preferences.getString(USERNAME) ?? "ak name";
        userEmail = preferences.getString(USEREMAIL) ?? "ak email";
        userPhoto = preferences.getString(USERPHOTO) ?? "";
      });
    }
```